# What's the advantage of passing credit cards via javascript vs. over the server (without saving it)?

Tags: javascript, pci-dss, credit-card

I've noticed current credit card gateways like stripe and wepay encourage sending the credit card number via their js framework (which would use some iframe jsonp magic to pass the data).

To my knowledge this way you don't need to worry about much of PCI compliance other than using SSL.

I understand that storing it can lead to many issues, from how it's stored (strength of encryption) to protect from employees access to the database, to protecting the database from SQL injection etc. But if it's not being stored, how could the data be compromised? If I'm worried about someone getting into my server and modifying the files to direct the data to themselves, then it won't make a difference what my code is.

My question is, what indeed are the security risks by having my server send the cc info (even without storing it) over having it sent by the browser/client?

Comment: The *short* answer to your question is that people use these methods to avoid having larger PCI scope and compliance requirements than they otherwise would.  The *long* answer is "having to do security righter in more places and with greater scrutiny."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The risks are more on the client end of things than your server side. What I mean by that is as a consumer I do not want my data going to your server for "processing" which then gets sent over to stripe/wepay. I dont know how you're transmitting the data or whether or not you're not storing it the way you say you are. Also from the consumer side of things if you're not PCI compliant I wouldnt go near your systems.

If you did however want to do the processing you'd have to find a server side library (of which ive not looked into) and make sure the data being passed is sent securely from the client to you and from you to the transaction handler.

The risks are the same on both sides, MITM. If I know my connection to the service is safe why would I risk using your system as a MITM?

Comment: So essentially, it's more about perceived security? This way anyone can see that they have nothing to worry about entering their card on my site. Since if it's sent to me, as secure as I may be, how does anyone else know if I'm legit or not, unless I'm known to be certified, trusted etc.

Comment: They dont, thats why we have certifications like PCI and why stripe (not sure about wepay) comply to those certifications.
Edit: most people dont know or care about it, they just get mad when their information is compromised. Dont be a statistic or get sued for it when you can use a service that will take the brunt of any issues due to their issues, not yours.